# SDL 2 hangs when polling for events

Tags: c, linux, sdl, sdl-2

I'm working on a simple GUI, and i'm trying to use the SDL library with little success. I'm developing in C language, and i can't switch to C++.
I'm using SDL 2.0.5 on a Linux workstation (Red Hat Enterprise Server 5 (Tikanga)).

The problem is that when i try to catch events, the window hangs. No response, 100% CPU usage, and i've to kill the process. Clicking on the "x" have no effect.
I wrote a simple test code to figure out the problem, but i really don't know what to do. It looks like the inner "printf" it's never reached.

Also, if i remove the event loop, SDL_Quit() is reached (no need to kill the process) and it gives me a "Segmentation fault".

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_events.h>

SDL_Window *mainWin;
SDL_Event mainEv;
int quit = 0;

if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0)
{
  printf("Init error.\n");
  return(1);
}

mainWin = SDL_CreateWindow("Title", 0, 0, 640, 480, 0);

while(!quit)
{
  while(SDL_PollEvent(&mainEv))
  {
    printf("Event!\n");
    switch(mainEv.type)
    {
      case SDL_KEYDOWN:
        quit=1;
    }
  }
}

SDL_Quit();
```

Comment: You are doing `quit=0` but your loop condition is `!quit` meaning that `quit` has to be non zero to exit the loop (and close the window). Changing this line to `quit=1` seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry, i made an error when copying the code. The problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
//#include <SDL_events.h>

int main(void)
{   SDL_Window *mainWin;
    ...
    ... // same up to:
    ...
      case SDL_KEYDOWN:
        quit = 1;
    ...
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

I pasted your code into "**sdl_t.c**", so compiled it with:

```
gcc sdl_t.c `sdl2-config --libs --cflags` -o sdl_t
```

I get a window that pops up and goes away when you press a key. There's obviously more to do ...

Have you seen this good tutorial?

http://www.willusher.io/pages/sdl2/

Comment: Solved. Your answer helped me to discover a probable conflict with different library versions. Thank you.